# Using Pearson Correlation Coefficient in computing user/item similarity

Tags: ds.algorithms, machine-learning, lg.learning

I'm researching for an algorithm for item-based/user-based collaborative filtering and I've come to this [site](http://devlicio.us/blogs/billy_mccafferty/archive/2006/11/07/netflix-memoirs-using-the-pearson-correlation-coefficient.aspx).

It uses Pearson correlation coefficient to compute similarity between users and when I read this line:

> A strength of this formula is that it takes into account average
>   ratings for each user. So if user a rates everything a 5 and user u
>   rates everything a 1, then they still have a similarity rating of 1.

I wonder why it would give a similarity of 1 because using the said equation which is the Pearson and using the given (user a, **5** and user u, **1**), it would give a zero for the numerator and denominator.

So what is the reason he said that the similarity of user a and user u with a rating of 5 and 1, respectively is equal to one? Is zero over zero equals to one?

Comment: @Valentas if that is true, How could you show correlation between the actual count of operations in your algorithm and the theoretical complexity?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pearson's correlation is undefined when the variance of one of the random variables is 0, I would look for a more credible source to read from.